# Check if all checkbox are checked not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I try to check if all checkboxes are checked and change the class of a button. But my code is not working and I don't know why.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check1" onchange="checkIfChecked();" class="checkThis" value="check 1"> Check 1<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="check2" onchange="checkIfChecked();" class="checkThis" value="check 2"> Check 2<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="check3" onchange="checkIfChecked();" class="checkThis" value="check 3"> Check 3<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="check4" onchange="checkIfChecked();" class="checkThis" value="check 4"> Check 4<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="check5" onchange="checkIfChecked();" class="checkThis" value="check 5"> Check 5<br /><br />
<a href="#" style="width:190px;display:block;" id="absenden" class="button-theme-disable">
    <span class="span_outer">
        <span class="span_right">
            <span class="span_left">
                <span style="width: 182px;" class="span_inner">Speichern & Schließen</span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
</a>
    function checkIfChecked() {

    if ($('.checkThis input[type="checkbox"]').not(':checked').length == 0) {
        $('#absenden').removeClass('button-theme-disable');
        $('#absenden').addClass('button-theme');
    } else {
        $('#absenden').removeClass('button-theme');
        $('#absenden').addClass('button-theme-disable');
    }

};
```

Here is a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/bt35r2tc/1/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change your selector to ".checkThis". Your selector is faulty because ".checkThis input[type="checkbox"]" means you're requesting all tags with a class of "checkThis" containing an inputy with type checkbox.

Comment: .checkThis input[type="checkbox"] won't work. This is "get all inputs of checkbox type inside a parent with checkThis class" and your code does not have a parent with this class.

Comment: .checkThis is not an ancestor of  input[type="checkbox"], so your selector doesn't retrieve any element

Comment: Okay, now my code look's like this, but it's still not wokring: if ($('.checkThis').not(':checked').length == 0) {

Comment: As a side note, you can also use toggleClass with a state instead of separate removeClass/addClass blocks: https://jsfiddle.net/bt35r2tc/6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.checkThis` itself is a checkbox. `.checkThis input[type="checkbox"]` will select checkbox in `.checkThis`. Try like following.

```
function checkIfChecked() {
    if ($('.checkThis').not(':checked').length == 0) {
        $('#absenden').removeClass('button-theme-disable');
        $('#absenden').addClass('button-theme');
    } else {
        $('#absenden').removeClass('button-theme');
        $('#absenden').addClass('button-theme-disable');
    }
}
```

**Full Code**

```js
function checkIfChecked() {
  if ($('.checkThis').not(':checked').length == 0) {
    $('#absenden').removeClass('button-theme-disable');
    $('#absenden').addClass('button-theme');
  } else {
    $('#absenden').removeClass('button-theme');
    $('#absenden').addClass('button-theme-disable');
  }
}
```

```css
/* Disable Theme */

.button-theme-disable .span_outer .span_right {
  background: url(http://mirsoftware.de/daniel/buttonrechtsdisable.png) no-repeat scroll right center;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 22px;
  display: block;
}

.button-theme-disable .span_outer .span_left {
  background: url(http://mirsoftware.de/daniel/buttonlinksdisable.png) no-repeat scroll left center;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 22px;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 4px;
}

.button-theme-disable .span_outer .span_inner {
  background: url(http://mirsoftware.de/daniel/buttonmittedisable.png) repeat-x scroll 0 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #878787;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 8pt;
  height: 22px;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 4px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}


/*Normales Theme*/

.button-theme .span_outer .span_right {
  background: url(http://mirsoftware.de/daniel/buttonrechts.png) no-repeat scroll right center;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 22px;
  display: block;
}

.button-theme .span_outer .span_left {
  background: url(http://mirsoftware.de/daniel/buttonlinks.png) no-repeat scroll left center;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 22px;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 4px;
}

.button-theme .span_outer .span_inner {
  background: url(http://mirsoftware.de/daniel/buttonmitte.png) repeat-x scroll 0 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #33427a;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 8pt;
  height: 22px;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 4px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.button-theme:hover .span_outer:hover .span_right:hover {
  background: url(http://mirsoftware.de/daniel/buttonrechtsmo.png) no-repeat scroll right center;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: White;
}

.button-theme:hover .span_outer:hover .span_left:hover {
  background: url(http://mirsoftware.de/daniel/buttonlinksmo.png) no-repeat scroll left center;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: White;
}

.button-theme:hover .span_outer:hover .span_inner:hover {
  background: url(http://mirsoftware.de/daniel/buttonmittemo.png) repeat-x scroll 0 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: White;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="check1" onchange="checkIfChecked();" class="checkThis" value="check 1"> Check 1
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="check2" onchange="checkIfChecked();" class="checkThis" value="check 2"> Check 2
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="check3" onchange="checkIfChecked();" class="checkThis" value="check 3"> Check 3
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="check4" onchange="checkIfChecked();" class="checkThis" value="check 4"> Check 4
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="check5" onchange="checkIfChecked();" class="checkThis" value="check 5"> Check 5
<br />
<br />
<a href="#" style="width:190px;display:block;" id="absenden" class="button-theme-disable">
    <span class="span_outer">
        <span class="span_right">
            <span class="span_left">
                <span style="width: 182px;" class="span_inner">Speichern & Schließen</span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's still not working: https://jsfiddle.net/o4fus9no/1/

Comment: Is this working for you? For my it's not working. The class are not changed :/

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use `each` in Jquery like this :

```
$(".checkThis").each(function(){
     if($(this).is(":checked")){     
         //checkbox is checked
     }else{
        //checkbox is not checked
     }
});
```